# Adding to extern array of struct. (C programming language)

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'm very new to C programming, so I apologize if this seems too rudimentary.
Here's a scaled down version of my problem, I'm basically trying to store a struct element in the extern array called r_a at index 0

header file:

```
  struct rescue_asset {
      char callsign[31];
      char type;
  };

  extern struct rescue_asset r_a[51];
```

main file:

```
  #include "header_file.h"

  int main(int argc, char** argv) {
      strcpy(r_a[0].callsign, "ID");
  }
```

why does this not work and what's the solution?

Comment: What makes you think this doesn't work? Any compile/run time errors?

Comment: when I try to run it I get BUILD FAILED, if I take that line out the program runs, why can't I have it defined in the header?

Comment: it is defined in the source unit somewhere, rather than the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extern declares the array but does not define it. Define it in the header file and use it in the main file

```
//Header file
struct rescue_asset {
char callsign[31];
char type;
}r_a[51]; 

//Main file
#include<header.h>
extern struct rescue_asset r_a[51];
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
strcpy(r_a[0].callsign, "ID");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: i have that imported, my mistake for not mentioning it

Comment: I tried this and got the error: rescue_assets.h:27:20: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘r_a’

Comment: I mistyped the structure instance, have fixed it

Answer (score 1):

You missed the ; from the end of struct block.

correct:

```
struct Foo {
    int j;
};
```

Comment: sorry, that was just a typo

Comment: That is not the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

extern just declares the array, you must reserve memory space for the array by putting

```
struct rescue_asset r_a[51];
```

in the main source file for instance

Answer (score 1):

```
struct rescue_asset r_a[51];
```

you should define this variable somewhere, may be you can define in main.cpp.
because in header file you have define the variable as extern.

Comment: I thought extern meant that it was essentially global? How would I define it? I thought I did that in the header file?

Comment: extern keyword just inform the compiler that the memory for that variable is already allocated so don't allocate another.
In case if you are using multiple source file where you are using the same global variable, then in the header file you should declare the variable as extern so that when you use that variable in another file then compiler will not create multiple copy of memory.